# Redis lexicographical search - result with score

Tags: redis

I would like to store items in a Redis sorted set with current timestamp as score and then do a lexicographical search that would return the list items with their score value. ZRANGE does that perfectly and returns data with score but I did not find a way to return score with ZRANGEBYLEX.

Is there a mechanism to return score with ZRANGEBYLEX?

Answer (score 0):

http://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex

This command supposes that all scores are equal in the sorted set, otherwise the returning set elements are unspecified (i.e. meaningless).

### EDIT

You can indeed use the SORT command:

```
sort mySortedSet alpha desc
```

With the correct `mySortedSet` sorted set name. If ascending order, remove the `desc` keyword.

Comment: @Niloct-> It appears that I won't be able to use score if lexicographical search is required. One workaround that I can think off would be to append timestamp in data and have all the items stored with same score. I wanted unique data in sorted set. The timestamp would make it non-unique and I would have to delete the old entry before inserting new one. Will see if there are any performance penalties associated with it. Thanks for pointing in right direction.